# What time/day format is openweathermap.org list.dt using

Tags: swift

I'm using the day forecast api at http://openweathermap.org/forecast16.  There is a parameter called list.dt. It gives a value in this format: 1406080800.

What format is that and how would I translate it to some human readable using functionality in Swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date is most likely in unix time (see [forecast5](http://openweathermap.org/forecast5), which states that `list.dt` is the "Time of data forecasted, unix, UTC".

Using Swift, you can use `NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: dt)` in order to convert this to a date. Then you can use standard `NSDateFormatter` to make it human readable.

Answer (score 1):

The `dt` is for date and time.

The value of `dt` is in a format known as `unix time`

Unix time is a system for describing time, which is the number of seconds elapsed since 00:00:00 (UTC), Thursday, 1 January 1970.

The value you have there (1406080800) is equal to `Wed, 23 Jul 2014 02:00:00 GMT` which is used in there example provided for the link you posted.

To use within `Swift` try the following:

```
    var date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: timeInterval)
```

To get a unix timestamp from `Swift` you can also use:

```
    let timeInterval = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a computed property to convert timestamp that you've got into Date. CodingKeys are here just to rename the meaningless `dt`.

```
struct Weather: Codable {
    private let timestamp: Double
    let temp: Float
    
    var date: Date {
        Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timestamp)
    }

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case timestamp = "dt", temp
    }
}
```